Downward Closed Set Family Where Every Non-Member Has a Small Subset Which Is a Non-Member
I am working with a downwards-closed set family $F$ in which every set $S\notin F$ contains a subset $C\subseteq S$ such that $C\notin F$ and $|C|=k$. The minimum possible number $k$ seems to be a very fundamental property of $F$, but I do not know how to find it in the literature. Has anyone seen this before? What is it called? for example, say that
$$
F=\{\{0\},\{1\},\{2\},\{0,1\},\{0,2\},\{1,2\}\}
$$
is a family of subsets of $\{0,1,2\}$. In this case the minimum possible $k$ would be $3$ because the only subset not in $F$ is $\{0,1,2\}$. However, if
$$
F=\{\{0\},\{1\},\{2\},\{0,1\},\{0,2\}\},$$
we can see that $k=2$, because $\{0,1,2\}\notin F$ and $\{1,2\}\notin F$, and $\{1,2\}$ is a subset of both. This idea seems very natural, and it must have been studied before, but I do not know what search terms to use to find it.

I have learned that this is called the Dual Helly number and is studied here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.11818.
